# OnLongClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-imageview, onlongclicklistener

I have an `ImageView`. I need to use `onLongClickListener` for ImageView. When I use this code nothing happen.

Code:

```
 gallery=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gall1);

 gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this));

            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                    imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);

                    imageView.setLongClickable(true);


     imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Press work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
            }

      });


  imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

        switch(event.getAction())
             {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
      {
   parms = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

            dx = event.getRawX() - parms.leftMargin;
    dy = event.getRawY() - parms.topMargin;
     }
 break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
{   
 x = event.getRawX();
 y = event.getRawY();
  parms.leftMargin = (int) (x-dx);
 parms.topMargin = (int) (y - dy);
                                    imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);
     }
 break;
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
 {

     }
   break;
 }

  return true;
    }
});
    }


 });
```

Comment: once View.OnLongClickListener replace it with OnLongClickListener and try.

Comment: @Harish: I tried. Is it possible to use OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener for same imageView?

Comment: instead of OnTouchListener use OnClickListener.

Comment: Finally got it..Use return false for OnTouchListener, both will works fine

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to enable long click by code:

```
imageView.setLongClickable(true);
imageView.setClickable(true);
```

The last line is probably not necessary but it also makes no trouble.

Comment: As per his requirement, only `setLongClickable()` is enough.

Comment: Is it possible to test longclick in emulator? I press mouse longclick nothing happen.

Comment: I just started a project with longclick in the emulator it works for me.

Comment: I used imageView.setLongClickable(true); above. But toast also won't appear.

Answer (score 12):

Its not necessary to do setLongClickable in the  code, its better when you define it in the XML

```
 android:longClickable="true"
```

Comment: UI stuff in XML mostly always better +1