# OnLongClickListener on image view is not working in facebook chat head implementaion

Tags: android, facebook, onlongclicklistener

I tried to create facebook chat head service. with refernce this [link](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) . OnTouch method working fine.On long press the image view I want to delete the image view from the current view.I used OnLongClickListener(), it is not working and shows no error.How to delete the image view On long press.

Comment: try adding longClickable="true" to the image view

Comment: @Arturs thanks for ur reply. I added that in my code.still it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are overriding on touch listener.

```
chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  private int initialX;
  private int initialY;
  private float initialTouchX;
  private float initialTouchY;

  @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialX = params.x;
        initialY = params.y;
        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

So you need to implement long click manually.

A pseudo code for that would be something like:

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialX = params.x;
        initialY = params.y;
        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
        action_down_time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        return true;
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //long click triggered if held for at least 2 sec (2000ms)
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - action_down_time > 2*1000) {
          your_long_click_callback_function()
        }
        return true;
```

EDIT:
You might also want to check the timings in ACTION_MOVE.

Comment: Ya. I overriding on touch listener. Now it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this lines while initializing your `ImageView`

```
imageView.setLongClickable(true);
imageView.setClickable(true);
```

OR in your layout XML file

```
 android:longClickable="true"
```

Those lines should enable the OnLongClick if it is not enabled

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289670/1364896) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289799/1364896)